# There is no implicit reference conversion from X to Y

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have an error on this class declaration:

```
public class MenuItemEstablishmentsRepository : VeganItemEstablishmentsRepository<MenuItem, Restaurant, MenuItemTag>
{
```

The error:

> The type 'Vepo.Domain.MenuItem' cannot be used as type parameter
> 'TVeganItem' in the generic type or method
> 'VeganItemEstablishmentsRepository<TVeganItem, TEstablishment,
> TVeganItemTag>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
> 'Vepo.Domain.MenuItem' to
> 'Vepo.Domain.VeganItem<Vepo.Common.Enums.MenuItemTag,
> Vepo.Domain.VeganItemEstablishment<Vepo.Domain.MenuItem,
> Vepo.Domain.Restaurant>>'. [Vepo.Data]

`MenuItem` and `VeganItem`:

```
[ElasticsearchType(RelationName = "menuitem", IdProperty = "Id")]
public class MenuItem : VeganItem<MenuItemTag, MenuItemEstablishment>
{
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Nest;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class VeganItem<TVeganItemTag, TVeganItemEstablishment> : DomainEntity<int>
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int IsNotVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
        [Required]
        public int IsVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
        [Required]
        public int RatingsCount { get; set; } = 0;
        [Required]
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<TVeganItemTag> Tags { get; set; }

        [PropertyName("veganItemEstablishments", Ignore = true)]
        public virtual ICollection<TVeganItemEstablishment> VeganItemEstablishments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Why can't it convert `MenuItem` to `VeganItem` when `MenuItem` inherits from `VeganItem`? What is the way around this error?

The super repository:

```
public abstract class VeganItemEstablishmentsRepository
    <TVeganItem, TEstablishment, TVeganItemTag> : 
    Repository<VeganItemEstablishment<TVeganItem, TEstablishment>, int> 
    where TVeganItem : VeganItem<TVeganItemTag, VeganItemEstablishment<TVeganItem, TEstablishment>>
    where TEstablishment : Establishment<VeganItemEstablishment<TVeganItem, TEstablishment>>
```

Comment: Why are the only complex `where` constraints on the repository? If the only valid `VeganItem` also has an `VeganItemEstablishment` constraint, why not define that rule on the item? But do you really need those complex constraints?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I don't know if I need the `where` constraints. I noticed when I added the constraints to `VeganItem` it meant I had to pass more types to `VeganItem` so looked clunky. We can't use abstract classes in tables, right? That is why I think I need all of those generic types if I want to make the code reusable.

Comment: How many similar but slightly different tables are you creating? How are you planning to query across them? That doesn't seem like a good relational database design.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Querying across them seems easy since they all inherit from the same super class, I can type them as the super class (but I am a front end dev so i may be wrong). But yeah I think I don't need all these subclasses. The Subclasses are very much the same. They only differ in that `tags` is a different enum. Maybe I should make that be an int? I just also thought this design would allow me to let them vary as the app matures which might be more flexible

Comment: @JeremyLakeman there could be up to 20 subclasses of VeganItem in the future. But maybe I could make VeganItem a concrete class and just use that, does that sound reasonable if they are so similar?

Comment: Don't try to make the schema too flexible, just try to meet today's requirements. YAGNI. If you are using table-per-heirachy, then you can add optional db columns that only map onto one subclass. Should tags be an enum? Do you really want to recompile when the client wants a new tag name?

Comment: What's the definition of `MenuItemEstablishment`?

Comment: Essentially, unless `MenuItemEstablishment` inherits _directly_ from `VeganItemEstablishment<MenuItem, Restaurant>`, you are running into wanting a covariant generic type in a situation where your generics are invariant. If either of the generic types parameters for VeganItemEstablishment are more or less derived from MenuItem or Restaurant, it doesn't match the invariant definition and won't resolve.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I am having some trouble getting rid of some unnecessary subclasses. How do we have two tables of the same type? I have 2 tables which hold those `tags` which were of type `GroceryItemTag` and `MenuItemTag`. They basically have 3 fields, one was the enum. I made a new Class called `Option` where the previous enum is just an int now but I need a table called `MenuItemTags` and `GroceryItemTags` both of type `Option`.

Comment: If you're going to simplify the schema, then write a migration sql script to move the data.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thanks, I just dropped the tables and created a new migration (app is not in production yet). But I still get: The seed entity for entity type 'Option' cannot be added because another seed entity with the key value 'Id:0' has already been added. I guess this is a new question :)